# Regular Expression for negative money values?

Tags: regex, currency

I want a regular expression which can work on the money related numbers. Currently I'm using this:

`^\$?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)(?:\.\d{1,2}){0,1}$`

My test set includes the following numbers, which I want to get declared valid. I've also mentioned with each number, what the validation result is when its validated using the above mentioned regex:

```
123456789012345 //valid
123456789012345.34 //valid

123,456,789,012,345 //valid
123,456,789,012,345.34 //valid

-123,456,789,012,345 //not valid
-123,456,789,012,345.34 //not valid
```

It seems to work on everything except the negative values.

Secondly, it seems to work on values with a `$` in the start. Can it be modified to accept `USD$` in the start, instead of just `$`, so that the following numbers would be valid ?:

```
USD$123,456,789,012,345
USD$123,456,789,012,345.34
```

Comment: Yes, it can. What have you tried? [Regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) for that purpose are trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really rather easy, actually:

```
^(?:(?:USD)?\$)?(?:-)?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

I've replaced `\$?` with:

`(?:(?:USD)?\$)?` - This matches an optional `$`-sign, optionally with `USD` in front of it

And added:

`(?:-)?` - This matches an optional `-` before the first digit

I've also abbreviated `{0,1}`, at the end, to `?`. Which is the same thing.

[*RegExr demo*](http://regexr.com?33q67)

If you want to do away with some of the clutter, as per Bergi's comment, you could simplify it a bit:

```
^((USD)?\$)?-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

I didn't want to touch the other non-capturing groups.

Comment: This would allow `USD` without the `$`.

Comment: `(?:-)` is a little bit exaggerating, isn't it?

Comment: @Bergi Well, it seems in line with the whole pattern OP had already. Didn't want to break the trend.

Comment: @Ahmad Be aware that this solution also allows a `$`-sign without `USD` in front of it. Not sure if that is actually what you wanted. If not: go with [MikeM's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14923785/165154), that only allows `USD$`, not `$`.

Answer (score 3):

To also match negative numbers, and to match `USD$` *instead* of `$`,
you could change the `^\$?` to `^(?:USD\$)?-?`